# Attempting to parse SQL like statement with Boost-Spirit 

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm a newbie in boost::spirit. I wrote the program to parse a SQL statement, like "select * from table where conditions". It compile failed. A large of template  errors reported. So, would somebody help me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

struct db_select {
    void exec() {}

    std::string filed;
    std::string table;
    std::string condition;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const db_select& se) {
    return os << "filed: " << se.filed << " table: " << se.table << " condition: " << se.condition;
}

template <class Iterator>
struct selecter : qi::grammar<Iterator, db_select (), ascii::space_type> {
    selecter() : selecter::base_type(se) {
            se %= "select" >> +qi::char_ << "from" << +qi::char_ << "where" << +qi::char_;
    } 

    qi::rule<Iterator, db_select (), ascii::space_type> se;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
            return -1;

    std::string str(argv[1]);
    const char* first = str.c_str();
    const char* last = &str[str.size()];
    selecter<const char*> se;
    db_select rst;

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, se, ascii::space, rst);
    if (!r || first != last) {
            std::cout << "parse failed, at: " << std::string(first, last) << std::endl;
            return -1;
    } else
            std::cout << "success, " << rst << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed my answer. I missed a syntax error (my brain is not the best C++ compiler). So now, in three steps my answer leads to a working full sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>**Edit** Finally behind a computer, revised answer:</sup>

There were three things to note

#### 1. Syntax errors

The parser expression contained errors (`<<` instead of `>>` as intended). This accounts for a lot of compile errors. Note the appearance of `*******` in the compiler error:

```
/.../qi/nonterminal/rule.hpp|176 col 13| error: no matching function for call to ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************
```

which is designed to lead you to the corresponding comment in the source code:

```
// Report invalid expression error as early as possible.
// If you got an error_invalid_expression error message here,
// then the expression (expr) is not a valid spirit qi expression.
BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MATCH(qi::domain, Expr);
```

Easily fixed. One down, two to go!

#### 2. Adapting the struct

In order to assign to your datatype as an rule attribute, you need to make it *fusion compatible*. The most convenient way:

```
 BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(db_select,
    (std::string,field)(std::string,table)(std::string,condition));
```

Now the code *compiles*. But the parsing fails. One more to go:

#### 3. Lexemes

Further more you will need to take measures to avoid 'eating' your query keywords with the +qi::char_ expressions.

As a basis, consider writing it something like

```
   lexeme [  (!lit("where")  >> +qi::graph) % +qi::space ]
```

- `lexeme` inhibits the skipper for the enclosed expression
- `!` Asserts that the specified keyword must **not** match

Lastly, look at the docs for `qi::no_case` to do case-insensitive matching.

### FULL CODE

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

struct db_select {
    void exec() {}

    std::string field;
    std::string table;
    std::string condition;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(db_select,(std::string,field)(std::string,table)(std::string,condition));

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const db_select& se) {
    return os << "field: " << se.field << " table: " << se.table << " condition: " << se.condition;
}

template <class Iterator>
struct selecter : qi::grammar<Iterator, db_select (), qi::space_type> {
    selecter() : selecter::base_type(se) {
        using namespace qi;
        se %= "select"
            >> lexeme [ (!lit("from")  >> +graph) % +space ] >> "from"
            >> lexeme [ (!lit("where") >> +graph) % +space ] >> "where" 
            >> +qi::char_;
    } 

    qi::rule<Iterator, db_select (), qi::space_type> se;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2)
            return -1;

    std::string str(argv[1]);
    const char* first = str.c_str();
    const char* last = &str[str.size()];
    selecter<const char*> se;
    db_select rst;

    bool r = qi::phrase_parse(first, last, se, qi::space, rst);
    if (!r || first != last) {
            std::cout << "parse failed, at: " << std::string(first, last) << std::endl;
            return -1;
    } else
            std::cout << "success, " << rst << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

### Test:

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
./test "select aap, noot, mies from table where field = 'value'"
```

Output:

```
success, field: aap,noot,mies table: table condition: field='value'
```

Comment: Added testcase and sample output